# How to raise error which is not raised by the method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two error classes `FirstError` and `SecondError`. I have a method that is risky and can raise Errors. It can raises `FirstError` but not `SecondError` and I am not allowed to change the given method.

There is a piece of code where I have to show message as well as raise the `SecondError` whenever first error is encountered. Currently I doing a patch fix which is not a good practice. What is the proper way to do this (if any) ?

```rb
class FirstError < StandardError
  def message
    "First Error"
  end
end

class SecondError < StandardError
  def message
    "Second Error"
  end
end

def risky_method # cannot modify
  raise FristError
end

begin
  risky_method
rescue FirstError => e
  e = SecondError.new
  puts e.message
  raise SecondError
rescue => e
  puts e.message
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing wrappers around code you use but don't own, catching low-level exceptions and throwing new ones that are at the correct level of abstraction for your interface are both good practices. It's the GoF Adapter pattern.

This is totally **not** the same thing as monkey patching - see https://dzone.com/articles/how-not-to-cut-your-source-with-sharp-knife-as-mon